# Newbie Problem. Adding number to variable while printing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm very new to python and programming and trying to add the number 2 so it comes out like this:

```
Oddur keypti skónumer 39 fyrir Línu sem kostuðu 3500 krónur.
En þá mundi hann að hún notar skónúmer 41
```

But I have no idea how to add a number while printing.

Basically I am trying to add "2" to the variable "skonr". Skonr = 39 and I'm trying to make it 41 at the end but 39 in the first part

My code:

```
    karl = " Oddur "
    kona = "Línu "
    skonr = 39
    kr = "3500"
    lina1 = "keypti skónumer "
    lina2 = " fyrir "
    lina3 = "sem kostuðu "
    lina4 = " krónur.\n En þá mundi hann að hún notar skónúmer "
    print(karl + lina1 + skonr + lina2 + kona + lina3 + kr + lina4 + skonr + 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use a format string to this kind of printing, and it allows you to do small adjustments to the value in the print context:

```
print(f"{karl} keypti skónumer {skonr} fyrir {kona} sem kostuðu {kr} krónur.\n En þá mundi hann að hún notar skónúmer {skonr + 2}")
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is mostly right. you just need to typecast the integers to string while printing. This can be done by wrapping them in `str()`:

```py
 print(karl + lina1 + str(skonr) + lina2 + kona + lina3 + kr + lina4 + str(skonr) + str(2))
```

output:

```
Oddur keypti skónumer 39 fyrir Línu sem kostuðu 3500 krónur.
 En þá mundi hann að hún notar skónúmer 392
```

Comment: The last one should be `str(skonr + 2)`.

Comment: ahhh ok didnt see the comment Tysm <3

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of ways to do that.

As you are in basics go with the simple solution.

for example:

```
a = 'this'
b = 20

print(a+str(b+2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add integers and string together, all in one print statement. You need to convert your integers to string. So instead of ...`skonr + 2`, give it like `str(skonr+2)`. Be sure to give the first `skonr` as `str(skonr)` too.

Answer (score 0):

For your purpose you could just use print with multiple arguments:

```
print(karl, lina1, skonr, lina2, kona, lina3, kr, lina4, skonr+2)
```

In this case, each argument is either a string or int.  With this its okay to have skonr+2 since we're just adding two ints.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that would resolve your problem:

```
def printer(*list_):
    str_ = ''
    for x in list_:
        if isinstance(x, int) or isinstance(x, float):
            str_ += str(x)
            continue
        if isinstance(x, str):
            str_ += str(x)
            continue
        str_ += repr(x)
    print(str_)
printer(karl, lina1, skonr, lina2, kona, lina3, kr, lina4, (skonr + 2))
>>>  Oddur keypti skónumer 39 fyrir Línu sem kostuðu 3500 krónur.
     En þá mundi hann að hún notar skónúmer 41
```

You could replace `print(str_)` by a `return` statements or do anything you want with this concatenated string